# Using T4 Templates in Visual Studio 11 Beta

Tags: t4, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to load a VS 2010 Solution in VS 11 Beta. When I try to run my T4 Templates I get this error:

> Error 1 Failed to resolve include text for file: T4Toolbox.tt

Is there already support for T4 Templates in Visual Studio 11 Beta? I found this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/garethj/archive/2012/04/03/what-s-new-with-t4-in-visual-studio-11-beta.aspx) that indicates I could use T4 Templates ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T4 is fully supported in the beta, but T4Toolbox isn't a Microsoft product, it's an add-on.  You'll need to get a Dev11-specific version.